# mysql php variable scope

Tags: php

I saw this block of code from some user contributed notes on php's official documentation and apparently I don't understand why the variable scope of the variable "$set" is going outside the for loop.

```
<?php
$sql = new MySQLi($host, $username, $password, $database);

$result = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM `$table`;");
for ($set = array (); $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); $set[] = $row);  
print_r($set);
?>


Outputs:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [field2] => a
            [field3] => b
        ),
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [field2] => c
            [field3] => d
        )
)
```

Comment: Simply because _that’s how it is_ in PHP … there is no extra scope for loops like in other languages. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: There is NO "variable scope for the loop"

Comment: and how is this variable scope question related to database?